# Any coding games made for learning how to build out ethereum smart contracts?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, eos

I recently saw this for learning how to code smart contracts on EOS: https://battles.eos.io but was wondering is there something similar in Ethereum where one can play a game to learn smart contract development for Eth?

Comment: https://ethernaut.zeppelin.solutions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cryptozombies is cool indeed,
also check out https://ethernaut.zeppelin.solutions/

Comment: I feel like Shawn deserved the reputation because he was first, but thanks :P

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend you look at [CryptoZombies](http://cryptozombies.io/), which does a great job at teaching you how to make a [CryptoKitties](https://www.cryptokitties.co/) like clone:

http://cryptozombies.io/

I think this tutorial does a great job teaching you about solidity, smart contract best practices, ERC-721 tokens, and building a game around these collectables.